# SharePoint is currently configured to block intranet calls

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, web-services

This happens when trying to get data from a remote service, I've only been able to find a solution to this exception for Sharepoint-server(farm)

The solution for a sharepoint farm is the following PowerShell script:

```
$farm=get-spfarm
$farm.properties.disableintranetcalls=$false
$farm.properties.disableintranetcallsfromapps=$false
$farm.Update()
```

What I'm wondering is, is there an equivilent solution for Sharepoint-Online? or is this simply not possible to solve?

**UPDATE**
I've created my own REST service, without an SSL and this works fine. What do you have to do in sharepoint-online to communicate with a self signed-cert httpS remote service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To communicate with an "https" remote service, you could use [SP Webproxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx)
This worked very good for me. It's like a middle-hand between your app and the remote service you're trying to fetch data from, or post data to.